# GitHub view PRs where I am directly requested and not my team

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/pulls/review-requested shows a list of all PRs where I am requested, including my team, which is auto-tagged on every PR in a given directory.

Is there any way of showing **only** my direct review requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From GitHub's [Search by pull request review status and reviewer](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer):

> | Qualifier | Example |
> | --- | --- |
> | `user-review-requested:@me` | `type:pr user-review-requested:@me` matches pull requests that you have directly been asked to review. |

which is different to the default which is used by https://github.com/pulls/review-requested:

> | Qualifier | Example |
> | --- | --- |
> | `review-requested:USERNAME` | `type:pr review-requested:benbalter` matches pull requests where a specific person is requested for review. ... **If the requested person is on a team that is requested for review, then review requests for that team will also appear in the search results.** |

---

You can:

1. Use https://github.com/pulls/review-requested and add `user-` to the default filter there so `is:open is:pr review-requested:your_user_name archived:false` becomes `is:open is:pr user-review-requested:your_user_name archived:false`; or
2. go directly to https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+user-review-requested%3A%40me+archived%3Afalse+ which uses `@me`:
   [image]

Comment: `user-review-requested:@me` is what does the trick, it's the difference between `user-review-requested` and `review-requested`

Comment: short version skipping archived, which is rare ymmv https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+user-review-requested%3A%40me+